# How to keep reusing one reference, to a value owned by a HashMap?

Tags: rust, ownership

I would like to make a recursive type using references, not smart pointers. I think this should work:

```rs
#[derive(Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
enum List<'a> {
    Cons(isize, &'a List<'a>),
    Nil,
}
```

Now all the references have to be owned by something with the same lifetime.

Because I want all references to equivalent objects to actually have the same value (so that I later can take advantage of `std::ptr:eq`), I had the idea to give ownership of instances of my data type to a HashMap. When I want a reference, I lookup an equivalent instance in the HashMap to get the reference to the "only reference this one" instance of that object.

E.g., I try to store `List::Nil` in the HashMap, so that when I want to use a `&Nil` in the future, I can look up `Nil` in the HashMap, and it will return me a `&Nil` that I can use — so that I have a guarantee that `std::ptr::eq(&Nil, &Nil)` will always be true, because the `Nil` they are referencing is the one owned by the HashMap. Because the references are immutable, it should be okay to have more than one around.

I thought this would work:

```rs
fn main() {
    use List::*;
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    let mut table = HashMap::new();
    table.insert(Nil, Nil); // give the HashMap ownership of a Nil
    let nil = table.get(&Nil).unwrap(); // get a reference to the HashMap-owned Nil
    table.insert(Cons(1, nil), Cons(1, nil)); // use that reference
}
```

But I get an error I don't understand:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `table` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> one_reference.rs:13:5
   |
12 |     let nil = table.get(&Nil).unwrap();
   |               --------------- immutable borrow occurs here
13 |     table.insert(Cons(1, nil), Cons(1, nil));
   |     ^^^^^^------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |     |
   |     |     immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

What causes this error?

And how can I actually keep all references of equivalent objects identical?

Comment: This doesn't work because `nil` holds the borrow to `table` for as long as it exists and for the same time you can't insert into your `table` because that requires borrowing `table` mutable wich isn't allowed. You can't borrow part of `table`.

Comment: @cafce25 why does `nil` need to keep borrowing table? Why can't it just get the value of the reference to table's `Nil` ?

Comment: Because it's a part of `table`. You can't do partial borrows.

Comment: Inserting to a hashmap can cause a re-allocation, which would invalidate the existing reference.

Comment: You might want to use a [slotmap](https://docs.rs/slotmap/latest/slotmap/) or similar instead, and store the keys it returns instead of storing the references.

Comment: @PitaJ at which line of my code could that happen?

Comment: Are you referring to re-allocation? It could happen at the last line, the second `table.insert`.

Comment: @PitaJ why would passing a nested type with a reference to a value cause the original value to be reallocated?

Comment: key-value pairs are not stored in separate allocations. On insertion, the HashMap may need to reallocate if there is not space for the key-value pair to insert, in order to grow the space available. This will move all of the key-value pairs in memory, invalidating any pointers to them.